# glReadPixels usage with glPixelStore

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, pixel, glreadpixels

I looked at multiple tutorials about glReadPixels but I'm confused:

void glReadPixels(GLint  x,  GLint  y,  GLsizei  width,  GLsizei  height,  GLenum  format,  GLenum  type,  GLvoid *  data)

The last argument is a void? 
I saw tutorials and they declared the argument as a vector, unsigned char, GLubyte,...
But what does it really mean?
And do you need to call glPixelStoref( , )?

Answer (score 3):

A `void*` is C/C++ speak for "pointer to block of memory". The purpose of `glReadPixels` is to take some part of the framebuffer and write that pixel data into your memory. The `data` parameter is the "your memory" that it writes into.

Exactly *what* it writes and how much depends on the [pixel transfer parameters](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer), `format` and `type`. That's why it takes a `void*`; because it could be writing an array of bytes, an array of ints, an array of floats, etc. It all depends on what those two parameters say.

Comment: One thing I would add (that may be helpful) is that, you cannot use glReadPixels on antialiased buffers. This means you may need to create own offscreen buffers that have copy of your scene but AA is disabled.